# How to apply Preview's Actual Size to every picture?

Tags: macbook-pro, preview

On Mac, when I view a comic using Preview, I open like 200 pages, then I click the `Actual Size`. But `Actual Size` only applies to one picture only, and when I view the next picture, I have to click `Actual Size` again.

Is there a way to apply `Actual Size` to every picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried and opened few different sizes pictures.
Then I used the "Select all" in the Preview Edit followed by "Actual Size".
It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

user44516's answer worked for me until I went through the pictures using <kbd>Page</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd>and <kbd>Page</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>.

However, I found using "Previous Item <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> from the "Go" menu worked.